# How to custom a live centos 7 image to boot from USB

Tags: centos, live-usb

I used this live image CentOS-7.0-1406-x86_64-GnomeLive.iso,
CentOS-7.0-1406-x86_64-KdeLive.iso to boot from USB to testing some servers. However, I'd would like to add some lib such as "ndctl" on this live image.

Please kindly advise me how to build the live image which include "ndctl" at boot USB up without download it everytime after boot.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Did you search someplace like [stackexchange](https://serverfault.com/questions/517908/how-to-create-a-custom-iso-image-in-centos)?

Comment: Your best bet is to just install CentOS 7 to the USB itself, install what you need, and then boot from it.

Comment: @NasirRiley The's not a comment but an answer! (and just what I was going to say)  If you post an answer and then ping me I'll upvote.

Comment: Customized iso is a large topic. Use kickstart and post if you have a problem https://devopsmates.com/make-custom-centos-7-rhel-7-cd-kicktart-file/

Comment: @Fabby no it is a work around. The op is asking to customize the iso and kickstart is the easy method

Comment: See https://serverfault.com/questions/517908/how-to-create-a-custom-iso-image-in-centos

Comment: @Fabby Done. In regards to the idea that it's a workaround, it does exactly what you want in a far easier way. You can install and modify whatever you'd like and use it as a portable installation.

Answer (score 2):

Your best bet is to just install CentOS 7 to another USB stick, install what you need, and then boot from it.

Comment: An edit and an upvote!  **;-)**